# Authorize.net showing Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller.

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, authorize.net

I am using the sandbox account of authorize.net. I have set the test mode to false in both admin and on sandbox.

Is this error occurring because i am on local server? My Url starts as http.

Comment: Please do one live transaction...Me to a faced issue like this, In live it's working fine....

Comment: So it's HTTPS issue ?

Comment: There is some problem in Sandbox mode... This is not related to HTTPS of local server

Comment: So what is the problem.

Comment: Sounds like an issue for xDebug. For security purposes, Magento masks the actual error. You can use xDebug to catch the specific error and see the actual error message. I've encountered this many times during development and have always been able to get the answer rather quickly.